# Finding exact position of tokenized sentences

Tags: python, tokenize, nltk

I want to extract sentences of text, but I need exact position of results. Current implementation of `tokenize.sent_tokenize` in NLTK doesn't return position of extracted sentences so I tried something like this:

```
offset, length = 0, 0
for sentence in tokenize.sent_tokenize(text):
    length = len(sentence)
    yield sentence, offset, length
    offset += length
```

But it doesn't return exact position of sentences because `sent_tokenize` removes some writing characters (e.g. newline, extra spaces and ...) outside resulted sentence boundary. I don't want to use a simple regex pattern for splitting sentences and I know in that case this problem is trivial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`PunktSentenceTokenizer`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer) directly (it is used to implement `sent_tokenize()`):

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer

text = 'Rabbit say to itself "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be too late!"'
for start, end in PunktSentenceTokenizer().span_tokenize(text):
    length = end - start
    print buffer(text, start, length), start, length
```

You could use `text[start:end]` instead of `buffer(text, start, end - start)` if you don't mind copying of each sentence.

Comment: what is ```buffer``` here?

Comment: @kkgarg: `buffer` is a builtin function in Python 2 (it is used here to avoid unnecessary copying/quadratic behavior).

Answer (score -1):

That was not so difficult, here is a simple solution:

```
offset, length = 0, 0
for sentence in tokenize.sent_tokenize(text):
    # fix ignored characters
    while text[offset] != sentence[0]:
        offset += 1

    length = len(sentence)
    yield sentence, offset, length
    offset += length
```

Comment: try `offset = text.find(sentence, offset)` to replace the `while`-loop.

Comment: the point is that you should avoid reimplementing existing methods that are documented, tested, and might be even optimized for you *unless* you have a compelling reason not to use them.